# BizTalk SMTP send mail with attachments (no orchestration, custom send pipeline component)

Tags: c#, smtp, components, pipeline, biztalk

I hope someone can help me out with this since when I drop a JSON test file in my rcv-folder the only result is that in the BizTalk console (in 'Running instances'), the message only states 'Queued (Awaiting processing)'. I am not sure where my issue is in the code.

I am supposed to receive a JSON which will contain some info and possibly multiple attachments (in Base64 format) and then send the mail out (with attachments in correct format, i.e. PDF, txt, xls) to a certain email-address. One of the requirements is to not use an orchestration. But I am stuck and have no idea what I am doing anymore. What makes this question different from others is that I have no orchestration in my solution. Everything will be processed in a custom send pipeline  component.
The sendpipeline (in encode stage) does contain my custom component and also the MIME/SMIME encoder. I am using the SMTP-adapter.

I have created the custom pipeline component with a wizard and my initial plan was in the form below:

1. Receive the file (in JSON-format. It will be transformed into XML for further processing). This will all be taken care of in my rcv-pipeline and this step already works for me.
2. Pick out all the necessary variables from XML needed to send in the e-mail. These variables are the ones I want to show in the E-mail text. Not sure how to explain it better.
3. Pick out all the attachments in base64, loop through them, convert to 'regular files' and then attach them to the mail (with correct filenames, extension etc.)

The XML looks like below:

```
ArchiveobjectsListErrands
  - ArchiveobjectErrand 
      * UUID (Here are the variables I need to show in the E-mail. The plain text, so to say)
    - ArchiveobjectListPaper
      - Attachments
        * Name
        * Extension
        * Size
        * Base64String (Base64 string which will be needed to be fetched (in GetAttachments) and then processed in (ProcessAttachments))
```

The code I have is below:

```
public Microsoft.BizTalk.Message.Interop.IBaseMessage Execute(Microsoft.BizTalk.Component.Interop.IPipelineContext pContext, Microsoft.BizTalk.Message.Interop.IBaseMessage pInMsg)
        {
            // 1) Read file with XPathNavigator (https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/standard/data/xml/extract-xml-data-using-xpathnavigator)
            XPathNavigator nav = ReadXmlFromMsgBox(pInMsg);

            var outMsg = pContext.GetMessageFactory().CreateMessage();
            outMsg.Context = PipelineUtil.CloneMessageContext(pInMsg.Context);  

            // 2) Pick out the necessary vars that the registrator requires
            GetRegistratorProperties(nav, pContext, outMsg);

            // 3) Read attachments
            var attachments = GetAttachments(pInMsg, nav);

            // 4) Processa attachments
            ProcessAttachments(pContext, outMsg, attachments);

            // 5) Send message along for further processing in the send pipeline
            return outMsg;
        }

        private void GetRegistratorProperties(XPathNavigator _nav, IPipelineContext _pContext, IBaseMessage _msg)
        {
            var bodyPart = _pContext.GetMessageFactory().CreateMessagePart();             
                     
            bodyPart.ContentType = "text/application";  

            bodyPart.PartProperties.Write("EmailBodyText", "http://schemas.microsoft.com/BizTalk/2003/smtp-properties", "EmailBodyText.");
            bodyPart.PartProperties.Write("Subject", "http://schemas.microsoft.com/BizTalk/2003/smtp-properties", "Registratorsubject - Create errand");

            _msg.AddPart("Body", bodyPart, true); // True for body but false for attachments

        }

        private void ProcessAttachments(IPipelineContext _pContext, IBaseMessage _msg, IList<Attachment> _attachments)
        {
            
            var msgPart = _pContext.GetMessageFactory().CreateMessagePart();
            //outMsg.Context = PipelineUtil.CloneMessageContext(_msg.Context);  

            int i = 0;            
            foreach (var item in _attachments)
            {    
                msgPart.PartProperties.Write("FileName", "http://schemas.microsoft.com/BizTalk/2003/mime-properties", item.filnamn+item.extension);
                msgPart.PartProperties.Write("ContentDescription", "http://schemas.microsoft.com/BizTalk/2003/mime-properties", item.contentType);
                msgPart.Data = new MemoryStream(BytesFromBase64String(item.base64));
                //bodyPart.Charset = "utf-8";
                msgPart.ContentType = item.contentType;  

                //_pInMsg.AddPart("Attachment part " + i.ToString(), bodyPart, false); 
                _msg.AddPart("Attachment part " + i.ToString(), msgPart, false); 
                i++;
            }
        }

        private IList<Attachment> GetAttachments(IBaseMessage pInMsg, XPathNavigator _nav)
        {
            XPathNodeIterator iterator =  _nav.Select("Path to attachments in xml");
            IList<Attachment> myList = new List<Attachment>();                        
            

            while (iterator.MoveNext())
            {
                XPathNavigator node = iterator.Current;

                Attachment atttachments = new Attachment();              

                atttachments.filenamne = node.SelectSingleNode("Name").Value;
                atttachments.extension = node.SelectSingleNode("Extension").Value;
                atttachments.contentType = node.SelectSingleNode("Mimetype").Value;
                atttachments.base64 = node.SelectSingleNode("Base64String").Value;

                myList.Add(atttachments);
            }

            return myList;
        }

        private XPathNavigator ReadXmlFromMsgBox(IBaseMessage pInMsg)
        {
            // Using XPathNavigator to avoid creating a XMLDoc in memory
            Stream originalMessage = pInMsg.BodyPart.GetOriginalDataStream();

            XPathNavigator _navigator = new XPathDocument(originalMessage).CreateNavigator();
            return _navigator;
        }        

        [Serializable]
        private class FileStreamFactory : IStreamFactory
        {
            byte[] _data;

            public FileStreamFactory(byte[] data)
            {
                _data = data;
            }

            public Stream CreateStream()
            {
                return new MemoryStream(_data);
            }
        }

        private static byte[] BytesFromBase64String(string msg)
        {
            return Convert.FromBase64String(msg);
        }
        #endregion
        }
```

I can show some example file of the XML if deemed necessary. I avoided it due to brevity and also since it is quite large.

I would greatly appreciate if anyone could help out with how the code is supposed to look to achieve what is needed, a mail with some text and attachments named correctly regarding filename and extension.

Comment: 1) Asking multiple question in a question will get your question closed.  2) Does the code work or do you have a specific issue?  3) Body text and Attachments are just different segments in a MIME encoded email, usually a plain text one is the first one.

Comment: @Dijkgraaf, thank you for clarifying. I hope this edited post will be clearer on what the issue is.
You stated that an MIME-encoded e-mail is really just two segments. Then am I setting the values incorrect in the method GetRegistratorProperties?

I am using bodyPart.PartProperties.Write(...) to set the 'plain text properties' (as far as I understand) and then _msg.AddPart("Body", bodyPart, true); // True for body but false for attachments to add all of the plain text field to the plain text segment of the e-mail. But this is perhaps the wrong way to do it?

Comment: If it has a status of  'Queued (Awaiting processing)', then it sounds like the host instance that is expecting to process is it, is not in a running state.  Check that the host instance the send port is on is running and that the Send Port is in a Started State and you don't have a schedule set on it.

Comment: @Dijkgraaf, thank you very much for your answer. This has led me one step further. I still have no email coming out but I am at least one step closer. I really can not believe that Microsoft does not have a tutorial or something of how to actually do this...
(P.S. For some reason I can not set your answer as the accepted one.)

Comment: That's because I posted it as a comment, and not an answer.  I've posted it as an answer.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Body text and Attachments are just different segments in a MIME encoded email, usually a plain text one is the first one.

If it has a status of 'Queued (Awaiting processing)', then it sounds like either

- the host instance that is expecting to process it is not in a running state. Fix: Start the host instance.
- the send port is not in a Started sate. Fix: set the send port to Started
- or the send port has a service window set on it.  Fix: disable the service window.